# Application crash when twitter login using FHSTwitterEngine

Tags: iphone, twitter, nsthread

Now I Integrate the twitter functionality with FHSTwitterEngine Rest API V1.1.

I was successfully Integrated and login functionality was worked great. But when I set the navigation to another controller based on success alert, the app was crashed with produce below error report

```
 bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x935f630: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
1   0x6fe0348 WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
2   0x2998afe __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
3   0x2998a3d __CFRunLoopDoObservers
4   0x2976704 __CFRunLoopRun
5   0x2975f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
6   0x2975e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode
7   0x6fe0310 RunWebThread(void*)
8   0x94179ed9 _pthread_start
9   0x9417d6de thread_start
```

I don't know why this error was happened. If any one have know the solution for this kind of issue I will really appreciate to you.

Comment: you can enable catch for all breakpoint to figure out which line of code is creating problem .

Comment: @Kunal Balani Thanks for your reply.I'm Implemented the twitter integration functionality on viewcontroller page.When the twitter login was success will redirect to anotherviewcontroller(feedpage). Here I'm display some data parsed from web service and load on the uitableview.

Comment: Th first node was displayed at index path row 0 and the crash report was appeared on second row.

Comment: i tough check your multithread operation like NSQueueOperation,Dispatch Queue...